# Как настроить osquery для сканирования компьютеров домена?

Tags: linux, windows

Стоит задача - в организации развернуть такую штуку как osquery, я немного про нее прочитал, понял что она из себя представляет, но вот один вопрос так и не решил.
Вот есть различные варианты установки, настройки с использованием Kolide, Fleet и прочих инструментов, но вот можно ли каким-то образом настроить ее таким образом, чтобы я указал например ip-адрес компьютера в домене или его имя, задал нужные параметры и нажал Enter?

Comment: А https://pkg.osquery.io/windows/osquery-5.11.0.msi чем не устраивает?

Comment: Видимо я не совсем понял вопрос. Ты хочешь получать инфу, когда сам захочешь инициировать сбор метрики?

Comment: Да, единственная сложность для меня - реализация сбора инфы по домену, вот у меня есть виртуалка с виндой 10 и установленной osquery, данная виртуалка находится в домене, я знаю параметры которые мне надо снимать, в каких таблицах они находится, но мне интересно: а возможно ли в консольной версии выполнить подключение к другому компьютеру для сбора данных, без использования Kolide и Fleet? Если да, то хотелось бы увидеть эту реализацию, а если всё-таки без помощи Kolide или Fleet не обойтись то хотелось бы посмотреть на нормальный гайд для виндовс

Comment: Ну раз у тебя есть сеть, есть админские права, доступ к тачке НЕ за NAT - в чём проблема запустить `osqueryctl` или как он там называется (я не пользуюсь, но рассуждаю на основе опыта)? Чем стучаться? Ну это хороший вопрос. Мне нравится `ansible`. Для windows он работает через `WinRM`. Можешь его попробовать напрямую.